# how to rerender component after amount of time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I have a component that renders another component and I want the child component to disappear after 2 seconds if an event does not happen and the parent will render it again with different arguments.

Right now what I did to the parent component-

```js
export default class BlockManager extends React.Component {
  state = {
        curr_trial: 0
    }
    
  key_pressed=(trial_data)=>{
    //do something
    
    this.next_trial()
  }
  
  time_passed = ()=>{
    //do something
    
    this.next_trial()
  }
  
  next_trial = ()=>{
    this.setState(() => ({ curr_trial: this.state.curr_trial + 1 })
            );
  }
  
  render() {
         return (
            <div>
                <Trial
                  color= {this.colors_combination[this.state.curr_trial]}
                  time_passed = {this.time_passed}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and to the child-

```js
export default class Trial extends React.Component {

    get_input = (keyboard) => {
        let trial_data = {
            key: keyboard.key
        }

        this.props.keyboard_pressed(trial_data)
    }
    
    get_image= ()=>{
    //do something
    
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div
                onKeyDown={this.get_input}
                tabIndex="0">
                {this.get_image(this.props.color)}
            </div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.get_input, false);
        setTimeout(this.props.time_passed, 2000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.get_input, false);
    }
}
```

But it is only done once.
I would be happy if you could help me find a way that if after 2 seconds no key is pressed the then call to time_passed function of the parent

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a `show` state in the parent component which indicates whether the child component should be rendered or not. Or you can use show to set `display: none` on the child styles.

```
return (
            <div>
                {show && <Trial
                  color= {this.colors_combination[this.state.curr_trial]}
                  time_passed = {this.time_passed}
                />}
            </div>
```

As far as I understood the problem, you should do these:

- Keep the logic in your parent component.
- Use `setInterval` if you want something to run on every n seconds. `setTimeout` runs the code after a delay, once.
- If an event happens and you want to postpone/cancel the child unmounting, remember to call `clearInterval` and do the cleanup. Then you have to call another `setInterval`.